# How to return an Object in Mockito 2.2 in Java? In my case returned object is NULL

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to return the response object and let the program to use some properties of response object.
I am using MockitoJUnitRunner.class and has mocked notificationService class.

I get the object as a null object. I need it to be the object that I have returned with the attributes.

```
    Request request = new Request();
    Element element = new Element("element");
    element.addContent(new Element("solnbr").setText("AWARD"));
    request.setData(element);

    SystemAccountResponse systemAccountResponse = new SystemAccountResponse();
    MultiValueMap<String, String> searchParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    searchParams.add("solNumber","AWARD");
    OpportunityRESTResponse response = new OpportunityRESTResponse();
    Embedded embedded = new Embedded();
    List<Opportunity> opportunityList = new ArrayList<>();
    Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity();
    opportunity.setId("1");
    opportunityList.add(0, opportunity);
    embedded.setOpportunity(opportunityList);
    response.setEmbedded(embedded);

    Page page = new Page();
    page.setTotalElements(10);
    response.setPage(page);
    when(opportunityRestService.getNoticeList(searchParams, systemAccountResponse)).thenReturn(response);

    notificationService.getNoticeListResponse(request);
```

Comment: Declare @Mock OpportunityRestService opportunityRestService;

Comment: @HemantPatel already declared.

Comment: Paste your OpportunityRestService class, it should have default constructor and it should not be a final class.

Comment: Why do you need to look at that class? The whole purpose of mocking is to bypass that class right?

Comment: Mockito create a mock class (proxy) from your class. To instantiate it, it needs default constructor. Or if has some constructor then you need to manually create mock object in setUp method.

Comment: can you give an example for this: "manually create mock object in setUp method" ?